# web service with spring security in java

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to secure a web service with spring and hibernate. Here is the
[trace of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sodE.png)

and in the `WebAppConfig.java` I'm writing

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-security.xml")
```

but it gives me `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `resources` folder should be in your build path.

If you are working with eclipse you can do it in this way:

```
Right click on Project -> Properties
```

[image: screenshot]

But it is better to convert your project to a maven project.

```
Right click on Project -> Configure -> Convert to Maven Project
```

Maven will create resources folder for you properly.